# EXT JS Progressbar

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a progressbar as below.
I want to display the progress text above the progessbar.
How to achieve this ?

Below is the progressbar image as how I want it.

```
             {
                 xtype : 'progressbar',
                 itemId : 'progressbar_searchresults',
                 width : 160,
                 style: {
                     color: 'green'
                 },
                 hidden : true,
                 textEl : 'progressbar_textElement'
             }
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, am unable to attach the image.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view,

Way one:

```
Panel
[{
item1 is lable(completed 10%)
},
{
progress-bar(10%)
}]
```

when even the progress bar's state was changed, then you need to change the label's value.

Way two:

or else you can display text over the progress-bar by using text property
 you need to add the following event inside the listeners

```
update( this, value, text, eOpts )

Fires after each update interval

Parameters
this : Ext.ProgressBar
value : Number //The current progress value
text : String  //The current progress text
eOpts : Object //The options object passed to Ext.util.Observable.addListener.
```